# Android Studio offline add `Android plugin for Gradle`

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I use `Android Studio 3.1.2` with `Gradle 4.4` and have to force `Gradle` to do **off-line work**, because when I use it normally (on-line), it takes to long to sync and fails. At first I got this error:

```
No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

So I downloaded `gradle-3.1.2.jar`, put it in `<project root>/libs/` and change `build.gradle` of my project to this state:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Now it seems that previous error is solved but another one is raised:

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ToolingRegistryProvider'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

How I can solve this problem?

***Edit***

I know the normal way is working on-line, at least for the first build. But there must be a way to add it off-line. Isn't there such way?

Comment: First try to build first time with online mode mode. After completing successfully, change it to offline.

Comment: I think if you need to sync your project in online mode just for one time and then you can keep offline work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080002/3395198

Comment: @PankajKumar I have to force Gradle to do off-line work, because when I use it normally (on-line), it takes to long to sync and fails

Comment: First update all your libraries to latest versions along with gradle then invalidate cache and restart your android studio.

Comment: @hasanghaforian You have to build atleast once as being in online mode, so gradle can sync project and download dependancy. After completion of first sync you can change it to offline.

Answer (score 1):

This is from android studio manual from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config).

> Turn on Offline Mode for Gradle: If you have limited bandwitch, turn
>   on Offline Mode to prevent Gradle from attempting to download missing
>   dependencies during your build. When Offline Mode is on, Gradle will
>   issue a build failure if you are missing any dependencies, instead of
>   attempting to download them. To turn on Offline Mode, proceed as
>   follows:

- Click File > Settings (on a Mac, Android Studio > Preferences) to
  open the Settings dialog.
- In the left pane, expand Build, Execution, Deployment and then click
  Gradle.
- Under Global Gradle settings, check the Offline work checkbox.
- Click Apply or OK for your changes to take effect.

Comment: I have to force Gradle to do off-line work, because when I use it normally (on-line), it takes to long to sync and fails.

Comment: I understand but you need at least 1 time sync your project in online mode so android studio can cache some data and allow you to keep coding in offline mode. In this state android studio doesnt have any instance of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2 so cant let you code in offline mode.

Comment: but there must be a way to add it off-line. Isn't?

Comment: i am sorry it is not feasible, you have as i told you before 1 time sync your project in online mode.

Comment: all are using off-line ...some body oly use off-line ...so change and try mode

Answer (score 0):

In android studio Go to **setting** menu > **Built,Execution and development** option > **Gradle** > mark/unmark on your **offline work** option and sync your project.try this.