# How to add libraries to gradle cache so that I can use android studio offline

Tags: android, gradle, offline

I have an android studio project on a laptop that has no access to the internet.

By default I have set it to work offline.

The problem is that now I wish to add new libraries to the project , and gradle , obviously, fails to sync.

Is there a way to download libraries from another computer that has an internet connection and have it saved to the offline computer so gradle can sync?

please note that I do not wish to add the jar to the libs folder, because this project may be shared with other people in the future who do have online access

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache read this link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio offline add \`Android plugin for Gradle\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678385/android-studio-offline-add-android-plugin-for-gradle)